# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS crash after updating from software updater

Tags: 12.04, updates

I updated my system today and noticed that there was a hardware update as well. I've never heard of a hardware update but I updated anyway. System had to be restarted after update but I was unsuccessful. I was informed that the system could only start in low graphic mode and that screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. When I try to start in low graphic mode, the system freezes. I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about analyzing and fixing it. It will be much easier to just do fresh installation of current Ubuntu version - 14.04 LTS.